# Get the element that closed the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

In my HTML I have this within one of my modals:

```
<a href="#" class="clicker" data-dismiss="modal">Click</a>
```

It hides the modal if this element is clicked.

However, I want to be able to get the element that closed the modal in jQuery, like:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event)
{
    var invoker = $(event.relatedTarget);
});
```

But this doesn't work. `relatedTarget` seems to only work for `show.bs.modal` and `shown.bs.modal` ([as per the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)).

How then can I get the element that caused the modal to close in the `hidden.bs.modal` event?

Comment: Don't you have it in the `event.target` ?

Comment: I have created a codepen to test @AllanStepps solution, but event.target points to the whole modal, not the element clicked.

Comment: What about `event.currentTarget`  ? (= The node that had the event listener attached.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Comment: Same result @AllanStepps. I managed to achieve the goal by other means, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[I have made a Pen to show how to achieve the desired result](http://codepen.io/bruno_krebs/pen/YpeaeG?editors=1010). As you can see in this example, the events spawned by Bootstrap do not share the exact element used to close a modal. They reference, as the `.target` and `.currentTarget`, the whole modal element itself.

So, in order to get the element that was clicked to close the modal, I have used jQuery selector functionality. Like this:

```
$("[data-dismiss='modal']").click(function() {
  $("#data-dismiss").html('#'+ $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

In this case, jQuery is searching for every element that has the attribute `data-dismiss` with the value `modal` and attaching, to those elements found, a callback function that is executed when they are clicked.

As you can see in the example that I have made, there are two buttons with this attribute. One in the modal's header:

```
<button id="header-close-button" type="button"
        class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

And another one in the modal's footer:

```
<button id="footer-close-button" type="button"
        class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Close</span>
</button>
```

Both these buttons have different ids that I set to show that you can check which one exactly was clicked - through the `$(this).attr('id')` on the callback function attached to the click event.